# Is it possible to use indirection with base R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, indirection

## Question: Is there a better way to indirectly reference a data variable in a function when using base R?

### Example Setup

I have a dataframe that I want to loop through some column (will vary in name) and build a string.  This is simplified, but illustrates the approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_original <- data.frame(id = 1:3, string = c("dog", "cat", "mouse"))
df_original

> df_original
  id string
1  1    dog
2  2    cat
3  3  mouse

# Easily can build string using base R with loop like this:
for (i in 1:nrow(df_original)){
  print(paste("I love my pet", df_original[i, "string"]))
}

[1] "I love my pet dog"
[1] "I love my pet cat"
[1] "I love my pet mouse"
```

### Problem:

I want to put this in a function with the ability to map different column names to the data-variable.  I was looking at ["indirection"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html?q=injec#name-injection), which I've used when writing function in DPLYR, but this doesn't work (and I expected that):

```
# Want to apply same idea inside function where df's column names may change,
# so I need to be able to quote them, but I know this is wrong.
myfun <- function(df, var){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, {{var}}]))
  }
}

# This fails:
myfun(df_original, string)

Error: object 'string' not found
```

### Works, but would like to do better:

I can `rename()` (DPLYR verb) the dataframe at the start of the function -- as seen below -- and get where I want, but this is a fuzzy area of R for me, and I'm hoping someone can explain how I might achieve that result in base R.  My actual use case (not this simplified example) has me building URL GET requests using lat/longs for origin/destination combinations, and the four columns are never consistently named in the source dataframes.

```
# Can rename the variable locally in the function, then use, but 
# this seems clunky.
myfun2 <- function(df, var){
  df <- rename(df, var = {{var}})
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, "var"]))
  }
}

# But it does work:
myfun2(df_original, string)

> myfun2(df_original, string)
[1] "I love my pet dog"
[1] "I love my pet cat"
[1] "I love my pet mouse"
```

I appreciate any suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: First you do not need any for-loop. directly build the string `with(df_original, paste('I love my pet', var))`

Comment: If you use `myfun <- function(df, var){for (i in 1:nrow(df)){print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, var]))}}`, just pass your column name in as a string `myfun(df_original, "string")`. Does your function really need to use unquoted column names? Note that `{{}}` is a tidyverse/rlang specific syntax and is not recognized by= base R function.

Comment: @MrFlick -- Actually, no it doesn't.  I just didn't think of that solution and that would just fine for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfun <- function(df, var){
     paste("I love my pet", eval(substitute(var), df))
}
myfun(df_original, string)
[1] "I love my pet dog"   "I love my pet cat"   "I love my pet mouse"
```

---

```
myfun <- function(df, var){
     paste("I love my pet", df[,deparse(substitute(var))])
}
myfun(df_original, string)
[1] "I love my pet dog"   "I love my pet cat"   "I love my pet mouse"
```

### Edit:

```
 myfun <- function(df, var){
   var <- deparse(substitute(string))
   for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
     print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, var]))
   }
 }
 myfun(df_original, string)
[1] "I love my pet dog"
[1] "I love my pet cat"
[1] "I love my pet mouse"
```

Comment: I appreciate the fact that this can be done above without a loop, but my real function has more things going on inside the loop than this simple example -- so in my case I still need/prefer the loop.  I didn't know how to do this technique you're showing, however, and I am very appreciative for this answer.

Comment: @wackojacko1997 even with the forloop, you still need to use `substitute(var)`. Check updated:

Answer (score 3):

As @MrFlick says in comments above, if your workflow can get you the string `"string"` rather than the symbol `string`, this is easy in base R:

```r
myfun <- function(df, var){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, var]))
  }
}
myfun(df_original, "string")
```

If you have the symbol, then @Onyambu's `deparse(substitute(...))` trick is what you need (although the argument should be `var`, not `string`

```r
myfun <- function(df, var){
   var <- deparse(substitute(var))
   for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
     print(paste("I love my pet", df[i, var]))
   }
 }
myfun(df_original, string)
```

As also commented, the `{{}}` stuff — while powerful — is tidyverse-specific; for more detail on how it works, see Hadley Wickham's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) book.